# Error with key-value observing with location manager

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I'm practicing google maps. I'm getting the error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ViewController:: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera1:GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.857165, longitude: 2.354613, zoom: 8.0)

    mapView.camera = camera1
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView .addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse{
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I'm creating observer path here:

```
func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = (change as AnyObject)[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as! CLLocation

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}
```

Comment: did you remove observer at viewWillDisappear ?

Comment: no is it necessary to remove observer